# Unable to connect to the LRS using the .NET Tin Can Library

Tags: c#, nuget, tin-can-api

I am trying to use the .NET TinCan Library for use within my own Learning Management System. I have included the TinCan 0.0.2 Nuget package in my application and uploaded the GolfExample_TCAPI test course. The GolfExample course loads at the following URL when testing locally:

```
https://127.0.0.1/TINCAN/MYCOMPANY/GolfExample_TCAPI%20(1)/index.html?
```

On looking at the launch documentation that I could find it seems that at a minimum you are required to pass in the endpoint, the auth, and the actor so I have attempted to do so using the dll as follows within my viewmodel.

```
var lrs = new RemoteLRS("https://cloud.scorm.com/tc/public/", "<username>", "<password>");

var actor = new TinCan.Agent();
actor.name = "John Paul Mc Feely";
actor.mbox = "jpmcfeely@hsl-data.com";

TINCANStartPage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + @HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + ":" +
                @HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + this.Course.BlobURL + "/index.html" + "?endpoint=" + lrs.endpoint + "&auth=" + lrs.auth + "&actor=" + actor.ToJSON();
```

When debugging I can see that this created the URL for the launch window as follows:

```
"https://127.0.0.1/TINCAN/MYCOMPANY/GolfExample_TCAPI (1)/index.html?endpoint=https://cloud.scorm.com/tc/public/&auth=Basic anBtY2ZlZWx5QGhzbC1kYXRhLmNvbTpwbGFzbWExMQ==&actor={\"objectType\":\"Agent\",\"name\":\"John Paul Mc Feely\",\"mbox\":\"jpmcfeely@hsl-data.com\"}"
```

This looks like the correct format according to the documentation that I can see but when I proceed the window launches with the URL as:

```
https://127.0.0.1/TINCAN/MYCOMPANY/GolfExample_TCAPI%20(1)/index.html?endpoint=https://cloud.scorm.com/tc/public/&amp;auth=Basic%20anBtY2ZlZWx5QGhzbC1kYXRhLmNvbTpwbGFzbWExMQ==&amp;actor={&quot;objectType&quot;:&quot;Agent&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;John%20Paul%20Mc%20Feely&quot;,&quot;mbox&quot;:&quot;jpmcfeely@hsl-data.com&quot;}
```

I then get a warning message as follows:

**[warning] There was a problem communicating with the Learning Record Store. (400 | Statement 3bd49829-dc0b-4daa-a689-71a84c44e6ad does not have an actor assigned.)**

If anyone could see what I am doing wrong here it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimally the query string parameters need to be URLEncoded. You would need to wrap `lrs.endpoint`, `lrs.auth` and `actor.ToJSON()` in `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`.

```
using System.Web;

TINCANStartPage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + 
    "://" + 
    @HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host +
    ":" +
    @HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port + 
    HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + 
    this.Course.BlobURL + 
    "/index.html" + 
    "?endpoint=" + 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lrs.endpoint) + 
    "&auth=" + 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lrs.auth) + 
    "&actor=" + 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(actor.ToJSON());
```

Based on the warning message it sounds like you are passing this through to TinCanJS. We'd need to see that code to troubleshoot further. The code that is instantiating the `TinCan` object needs to pass it the `url` to parse, which seems to be working, but the actor is not being found possibly because of the incorrect URL encoding.

Note that the fact that you are getting a 400 status with that response means it is connecting to the LRS successfully, just what is sent in the request isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by doing the following on the ViewModel:

```
//Initialize the LRS
var lrs = new RemoteLRS("https://cloud.scorm.com/tc/public/", "<username>", "<password>");  

//Initialize the TinCan Actor for Launch String
this.Actor = new TinCan.Agent();
this.Actor.name = this.User.Forename + " " + this.User.Surname;
this.Actor.mbox = this.User.Email;

//Construct the TinCanStartPage
TINCANStartPage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + @HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + ":" +
                @HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + this.Course.BlobURL + this.LaunchPage;
```

Then on the view where the TinCan window is launched from I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myActor = '@Html.Raw(Model.Actor.ToJSON())';        
    var launchLink = '@Model.TINCANStartPage' + '?endpoint=' + '@Model.LRS.endpoint' + '&auth=' + '@Model.LRS.auth' + '&actor=' + myActor;
    window.open(launchLink, "SCORM", "width=1140,height=760,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0");

});

function relaunch() {        
    var relaunchLink = '@Model.TINCANStartPage' + '?endpoint=' + '@Model.LRS.endpoint' + '&auth=' + '@Model.LRS.auth' + '&actor=' + myActor;
    window.open(relaunchLink, 'SCORM', 'width=1140,height=760,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');
}
```

Comment: I then moved this logic back to the ViewModel after Brian so kindly pointed out how the encoding was done